# Чтение памяти других процессов без открытия HANDLE

Tags: windows, memory

Можно-ли как-то читать память других процессов без открытия HANDLE в Windows?
Догадываюсь что из Ring3 я этого сделать не смогу, но как тогда?
Писать драйвер?
Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то читать память других процессов без открытия HANDLE в Windows?

Нет, никак. Ни в пользовательском кольце защиты, ни в режиме ядра.

Хэндл, он же дескриптор — это уникальный идентификатор, позволяющий Windows отличать различные сущности даже одного типа. Без него вы не сможете сказать операционной системе, над чем именно нужно произвести то или иное действие.

Это касается не только процессов, а вообще *всех* программных сущностей.